# CMake not detecting JNI properly with Temuring jdk 8 in MacOS

Tags: java, cmake, java-native-interface, eclipse-temurin

I am building a library on Mac Big Sur using Java 8 from Adoptium (Eclipse Temurin).

To install Java, I am using the following commands:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask temurin8
```

Then, I export JAVA_HOME like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

And it properly exports it. When I execute `echo $JAVA_HOME`, it returns:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

However, while building the library, it tries to find JNI, and it is returning the following lines:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.24.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_INCLUDED_PATH JAVA_INCLUDED_PATH2 AWT)
```

Is there anything else necessary to make this work on MacOS?

Notes:

- I installed cmake using brew (`brew install cmake`).
- I have already searched in Google and StackOverflow, and none of the proposed solutions worked (I have also checked the recommended similar questions while creating this one).
- I checked the variable values in the `FindJNI.cmake` file and everything seems correct (it should find it).

  - In `FindJNI.cmake`, the value of `JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` is correct (`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk/Contents/Home/include`), and `jni.h` is inside that directory. However, `find_path(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH 'jni.h' $(JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES))` is not setting `JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH` properly.
  - I created a dummy project using `find_path(TEST 'jni.h' '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk/Contents/Home/include')`, looking for `jni.h` and it works. `TEST` contains the correct value.

Thank you.

Edit:

- This is the call to `find_package`:

  ```
   find_package(JNI 1.7 REQUIRED)
  ```

Comment: Can you show the `find_package` invocation for JNI?

Comment: Hi @Botje, I was finally able to compile this. It does not actually "solve" the problem, since I had to set the variables manually, but this worked for me.  I posted an answer with it.

Regarding the `find_package` invocation, I just added it to my question. It indicates the minimum version as 1.7. I am using 1.8, so it should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to reproduce your issue but could not. All the mentioned variables are just present and correct for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this by setting the requested variables as flags for cmake. I just appended the following to my cmake call:

```
cmake ... -DJAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8) -DJAVA_INCLUDE_PATH=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)/include -DJAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)/include/darwin -DJAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)/include
```